# openGL - creating a bending surface

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, shader

I've been studying openGL for a while, I'd like to create a book with the page turning effect, but the pages should "bend" themselves. So now I'm wondering how one could bend a surface and animate it in openGL. Sounds like a multiple-per-vertex-shaders depending on the position of the vertex, isn't it?

Or perhaps a single shader with multiple branches

Comment: If you're on iOS, you may [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2646810/1262542), though the code might be interesting anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Page turning is implemented as a cone that varies its radius and apex angle at various stages of the "curl". [Here](http://wdnuon.blogspot.com/2010/05/implementing-ibooks-page-curling-using.html) is a tutorial for iOS that walks through the math. The original paper by Xerox PARC is [here](http://www2.parc.com/istl/groups/uir/publications/items/UIR-2004-10-Hong-DeformingPages.pdf).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

Implement the bending as a curve equation, and apply that curve to the vertex position depending on the distance from the binding (you may use an additional vertex attibute for this).

---

#### Update as per suggestion (formerly comment):

If look at a cone you can see, that it consists of a circular curve (around its axis) which is tapered to its tip. This is the curve you'd create for a cone method page curl effect. The surface of a cone with its tip at the origin and its axis being Z is described by the analytic surface

```
S(u,v) = (x*cos(u*2*pi) + y*sin(u*2*pi))*v + z*v*a
```

where x,y,z are the cartesian unit vectors and a = 2*tan(opening angle)

Comment: What kind of curve? How would one take into account the position of the user's touch input? Sorry, but this answer seems VERY vague to me, given that a even simple google search yields the "cone" paradigm as well as samples for such an effect.

Comment: If look at a cone you can see, that it consists of a circular curve (around its axis) which is tapered to its tip. This is the curve you'd create for a cone method page curl effect. The surface of a cone with its tip at the origin and its axis being Z is described by the analytic surface `S(u,v) = (x*cos(u*2*pi) + y*sin(u*2*pi))*v + z*v*a`, where x,y,z are the cartesian unit vectors and `a = 2*tan(opening angle)`.

Comment: I didn't disagree that it was a curve, only that the answer was vague. The comment above would a nice edit to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very nice GLSL implementation (with antialiasing and analytic shadows) of a page curl effect by Hewlett-Packard, which is the part of WebVfx. Here is the source code:

http://rectalogic.github.io/webvfx/examples_2transition-shader-pagecurl_8html-example.html

The project is licensed using a BSD-style [License](http://rectalogic.github.io/webvfx/license.html).